# OAuth 2.0 refresh token is not available?

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth

I have a web based application which use Google OAuth2.0 as the login framework. It works nicely previously until yesterday. The applcation couldn't get the refresh token after the access token expired.

How can I remove the following error?

`**PHP Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available.`

Below is my code :

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 access token can be expired, and you have to refresh it by using "refresh token" -- it is always with access token.